# Check If Array Has Value in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, ecmascript-2016

I have to check if any of the "cuesData" has a value or length greater than 0. 
In my code below, i can only check the first array but not the others.

[image]

**TS**

```
checkValues(values) {
    const result = Object.values(values).every((value) => value[1].cuesData.length > 0);
    return result;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngIf="checkValues(values) === true">
```

**JSON**

```
  [
      [
        "videoData__1",
        {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "Pale Blue Dot",
          "stoppedAt": 97.834667,
          "cuesData": [
            {
              "startTime": 25.335678,
              "endTime": 35.335678,
              "description": "fqff"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      [
        "videoData__2",
        {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "Big Buck Bunny",
          "stoppedAt": 247.57881,
          "cuesData": []
        }
      ],
      [
        "videoData__3",
        {
          "id": 3,
          "title": "Elephants Dream",
          "stoppedAt": 404.585327,
          "cuesData": []
        }
      ]
]
```

Comment: You could do the check in a `function` or component property and reference that property from your `ngIf`.

Comment: what is the error you are facing

Comment: cuesData is property of object not any array element.*ngIf="values[0][1].cuesData.length > 0"

Comment: @ShlokNangia. It should check every array not just the first array. Every array has a cuesData array, so i need to check if at least one cuesData has a value or a length greater than 0

Comment: @Joseph, Do you mean like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-angular-starter-yiye8g

Comment: @ManirajMurugan. Pls check edited post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change,

```
checkValues(values) {
    const result = Object.values(values).every((value) => value[1].cuesData.length > 0);
    return result;
}
```

**To**

```
checkValues(values){
  const result = Object.values(values).some((value) => value[1].cuesData.length > 0);
  return result;
}
```

> **Working Stackblitz:**  https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-angular-starter-j4yypu

Here `.every()` method will check that all conditions should met but whereas **[some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** method works that at least one condition has been true..

Stackblitz without cuesdata length: https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-angular-starter-cfpxa5

Comment: Is this not an expensive operation in template?

Comment: @Joseph, This is not an operation in template side and you are handling the logic in ```.ts``` file only so this is best approach only.. It is always better to handle the logics in typescript file..

Comment: @Joseph, Also added another example that has another scenario of not having any cues data values in any of the array.. Hope this helps and I hope that this solution won't cause any performance issue..

Answer (score 0):

You can use some method for this:

```
*ngIf="CheckValues(values)"
```

function:

```
CheckValues(values : any[]){
   return values.some(v=>v[1].cuesData&&v[1].cuesData.length); //if any array has cuesData, some will return true
}
```

more about `some` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: Is this not an expensive operation in template?

Comment: yes it is, if you want, you can check this when you get your data and set any variable for ng if

Comment: My data is changing always.